# Fade out custom view while scrolling

Tags: android, animation

There is a custom fixed searchview, under the toolbar:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.mobium.reference.views.AdvancedSearchView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/catalogItems"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
```

I want to make fade out animation for it while scrolling recycler view down (Google I/O makes it with toolbar).

[image]

May be there is any way to do it with design support library, not sure how.

I'll be glad for any tip, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Add a scroll listener to toggle visibility:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        if(dy > 0){
            searchView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else{
            searchView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

`animateLayoutChanges` to animate visibility:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
```

---

Unrelated to the question:

Preemptive strike on your margin issue. If you want the `recyclerView` to fill in the area occupied by the search box, you should be using paddingTop with clipToPadding set to false:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/catalogItems"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:clipToPadding="false"/>
```

Comment: View is fading out this way, but searchview functional (as edittext field) doesn't work, guess recyclerview stands at top of it

Comment: You can swap the position of the search view and recycler view. The last child is on top.

Answer (score 0):

[recyclerview hide on scroll sample](https://github.com/mzgreen/HideOnScrollExample)
 part3 is useful for you.